# Is this how to translate python generators to C#

Tags: python, c#, translation

So I need this python code or alike it to translate to C# in a generator format

```
x = [5, 9, 0, 7, 2]
y = [i*i for i in x if i%2==0]
print(y) #outputs the full list
```

Will the resulting code will be this, assuming the Main block is written:

```
int[] x = new int[] {5, 9, 0, 7, 2};
var y = (from i in x where i%2 == 0 select i*i).ToArray();
Console.Writeline(y); //outputs Array object
```

It uses LINQ library

Comment: `Will the resulting code will be this` eh.. what?

Comment: @RandRandom inside the Program.cs class and Main method

Comment: The C# array declaration is wrong - either drop the "int[]" from the right side or change it to "new int[]".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = new [] { 5, 9, 0, 7, 2 };
var y = x.Where(n => n % 2 == 0).Select(m => m*=m);
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(",",y)}]");
```